# Toggle collapse of sibling li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu with HTML as follows,

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="sub-heading">Sub Heading</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
    </ul>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

When the subheading is clicked, the li below the subheading in this case A,B should collapse. This functionality should toggle. How do I achieve it using vanilla JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Toggle Element Siblings

Toggling elements can be accomplished simply using `classList.toggle`.  Instead of adding an event listener for each sub-heading, it would be better to create one listener on a common ancestor (e.g., `main-menu`) and sniff if the clicked element (e.g., `event.target`) is a sub-heading and take action if so.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.main-menu');

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let target = e.target, el = target;
  if (target.classList.contains('sub-heading'))
    while (el = el.nextElementSibling)
      el.classList.toggle('hide')
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="sub-heading">Sub Heading</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil", you are assuming that there are more than one `sub-heading`. However, OP's question only shows one and that's why my answer adds an event listener to *the* sub-heading. If it was the case where there would be more than one sub-heading than it could be optimized.

Comment: @LuísRamalho I like your quote, but I've never heard it. I have heard that *money is the root of all evil.*  There are so many pre-mature optimizations, that I bet you would disagree with it, or I can point out ways your solution has been "pre-maturely optimized", they are just taken for granted.  Regarding my assumption, I did not have any. I like to write with scalability in mind.  One of the things that creep up are items added in the future. My common sense kicks in when I see a menu with only one sub-heading... there will be more sub headings, otherwise there may be no reason for just one

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery, you can for example use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) coupled with [`toggleAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute) in vanilla JavaScript to achieve that, like so:

```js
let subHeading = document.querySelector(".sub-heading");
subHeading.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let nextSibling = subHeading.nextElementSibling;
  while (nextSibling) {
    nextSibling.toggleAttribute("hidden");
    nextSibling = nextSibling.nextElementSibling;
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="sub-heading">Sub Heading</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings()` function to get siblings li and `toggle()` to show hide.

```
$('.sub-heading').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

```js
$('.sub-heading').click(function(){
   $(this).siblings().toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="sub-heading">Sub Heading</li>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
    </ul>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution use `children` property to get all children of parent class sub-menu use `reduce` method

```js
let subMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-menu")[0];
let subHeading = document.getElementsByClassName("sub-heading")[0];
//subMenu.firstChild.addEventListener("click", () => {
subHeading.addEventListener("click", () => {
  [...subMenu.children].reduce((acc, item)=>{
     
        item.toggleAttribute("hidden");
     
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="sub-heading">Sub Heading</li>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
  </ul>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```